# Ingres with Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, ingres

I have a classic ASP application which is connecting to Ingres 9.3 database. The classic ASP website in IIS has windows integrated security enabled. It connects to Ingres for reading data, and its passing logged in user name and password to ingres for connection. We cant give read access to all the users, so I need some way of identity impersonation for ingres connection (the way we do in .NET applications through web.config). When web site is connecting to ingres it should use admin account from server, not the local user's account.

Ingres creates a security ticket/tocken kind of file when somebody tries to connect to it. Is there any way of overriding these settings?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the the users to a GROUP and assign the relevant permits (using GRANT) to the group. When connecting to Ingres, I assume via ODBC, you provide the GROUP name as part of the connection string. Whilst you still have to assign users to a GROUP the overall performance will be better when accessing the table.

I think you should be able to add a group to your connection string using:

```
DSN=data_source_name;GROUP=mygroup
```

For the complete list of DSN attributes see http://docs.ingres.com/Ingres/9.3/Connectivity%20Guide/connectstringkeywords.htm.

Comment: Hi grantc, thanks for the response. Is it possible for you to give me some example connection string for that. I am using system DSN for connection.